# AsteriskNOW-3.0.0-i386 'system admin' Module is not updating

Tags: asterisk

AsteriskNOW-3.0.0-i386

While updating 'system admin' module i am getting the following error:

System Admin cannot be installed:

```
PHP Component Zend Guard Loader is required but missing from you PHP installation.
File /usr/sbin/incrond must exist.
```

Please try again after the dependencies have been installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

search for package php-zend-guard-loader on website pkgs

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue and was the first hit on a google search:

http://www.freepbx.org/forum/freepbx/general-help/2-10-upgrade-issue

Answer (score 0):

incrond

you have to install either 32 or 64 bit

```
wget http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/x86_64/rpmforge/RPMS/rpm-macros-rpmforge-0-6.el6.rf.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh rpm-macros-rpmforge*
yum install incron
```

For freepbx commercial module look at this link:

http://wiki.freepbx.org/display/FPG/Installation+on+CentOS+and+RHEL+based+systems